# Pushing custom gem-changes to Heroku

Tags: heroku, apple-push-notifications

I'm having problems with certain model associations in my web-app deployed on Heroku.

On my local machine I made some custom changes to the apn_on_rails gem, which is installed in my **~/.bundler/ruby/1.8**/ directory, but I have a feeling that the changes here aren't being pushed to Heroku, or that Heroku simply fetches the gems as they were initially created from the appropriate repository and installs a non-customized copy when I deploy my app to the site.

Any ideas on how to include my customized copy of apn_on_rails, and not the one I initially installed?  Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe http://cyber-hobo.blogspot.com/2010/09/sneak-custom-gem-into-heroku.html could help you

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your response, fuzzyalej.  My suspicions were correct, so what I did was fork the gem, added my personal changes, uploaded my customized gem to my personal github account, and then pointed my Gemfile to that account.  It might not be the best solution, but it works for now. =P

Comment: Did you do anything special other than point to your custom github version? I've tried doing that, and Heroku installs the gem fine (from best I can tell), but then the app crashes not able to find my gem. I added gem 'showoff', :git => "git://github.com/dissolved/showoff.git"